# Vue.js working with anime.js

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, anime.js

I'm having a Vue.js project with Anime.js installed as a dependence.

[My code is in a CodeSandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/7m4732x620)

```html
<template>
    <div 
        ref="logo" 
        class="logo" >
        <svg viewBox="0 0 435.6 141.4" >
            ...
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>     

<script>
import { logoAnimation } from "../assets/animate";

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    mounted() {
      logoAnimation.init(this.$refs.logo);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I assume what I do wrong is in the method, I don't know how to get all the SVG paths to animate them properly and I want the animation to start as soon as the page loads.

```js
import anime from "animejs";

export function logoAnimation(element) {
  anime({
    targets: element,
    strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    easing: "easeInOutSine",
    duration: 2000,
    delay(el, i) {
      return i * 250;
    }
  });
}
```

[Here you can check what is my goal and what I try to accomplish using Vue also.](https://liveweave.com/Rb3tV3)

Comment: Please include the code in the question description. A question should be self-contained and links to off-site resources should mostly serve as additional sources.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thank you for your feedback. I edited my post so I think now is more clear.

Comment: Please avoid images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mounted()` should not be declared within `methods`. It should be directly in the object.

Also, the animation you are using requires (a list of) `path` elements. So I moved the `ref` to the `<svg>` element and added `.children`:

```html
<template>
    <div 
        class="logo" >
        <svg viewBox="0 0 435.6 141.4" ref="logo">
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  mounted() { // not inside methods anymore
    logoAnimation(this.$refs.logo.children); // added.children
  }
};
```

[**Updated CodeSandbox here.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/r4vll0p0rp?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue)